# C# Process cannot get output with a special exe

Tags: c#, redirect, process, pipe, output

There is a program named `mbinfo.exe`, which is a part of [mbsystem](https://www.mbari.org/products/research-software/mb-system/). It was designed for Linux (https://github.com/dwcaress/MB-System). GMT (a Geographic tools provider) build a Windows version and I want to invoke it to get its output. When I run it in terminal, it works fine:

[image: terminal image]

But when I run it from C#, I cannot get the output. The C# code should be correct, because it can get output from other programs.

I tried to use `...> output.txt` in terminal, and it suprisingly write nothing into the file; instread, the output is still displayed on the screen. I guess it writes to the console with a special stream, neither stdout or stderr. I think it is possible because it is designed for Linux.

I provide the program on my website: [download](http://disk.autodotua.top/Disk/Download?fileId=bc473e82668c4c0087983d507956d741). You can run the command

```
./mbinfo.exe -f 211 -i a.xtf
```

to test it.

Here are codes:

async:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = GetFileName(),
                    Arguments = GetArgs(),
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,

            };

            process.Exited += (sender, args) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
                process.Dispose();
            };
            process.ErrorDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;
            process.OutputDataReceived += Process_ErrorDataReceived;
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            return tcs.Task;
```

sync:

```
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = GetFileName(),
                    Arguments = GetArgs(),
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                },

            };

            process.Start();
            string result = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd() + process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();
            return result;
```

I even tried to use Powershell SDK in C# but still get nothing:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"C:\programs\gmt5\bin\mbinfo.exe-f 211 -i C:\Users\autod\Desktop\test\a.xtf");
var result = ps.Invoke();
//return result[0].ToString();
```

All get is an empty result: `""`, while I can get all results when running other exes.

So I think **the key of this problem is that this program (`mbinfo.exe`) uses a non-standard output stream rather than stdout/stderr.** I don't know how to capture this stream in C#.

Could anyone help me and tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: When sending data make sure you do a Flush() so data gets sent.

Comment: @jdweng I did't use input stream, only use StartInfo.FileName and Args.

Comment: What do you get if you run `mbinfo blah 2>err.txt` to redirect stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried, it generate a empty file.  it may use a not standard stream, neither the stdout nor the stderr.

Comment: Keep re running and incrementing the number up to 9 (check between each run because > will overwrite)

Comment: You have a race condition.  You have to wait until program finishes before reading the results.  After Start() you need a look to wait until program finishes before reading all the data.  If you put code after WaitForExit() the data will get lost.  So I would add a terminating character to the StandardOutput and after Start() loop until the end character is found.

Comment: @Caius Jard unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried to use read+while or readline+while, before or after WaitForExit(), got the same result. and I can get result running other programs, so it has little possible with incorrect codes.

Comment: Did you append all the receive strings together?  The last string will return a return.  Without the appending you are getting the last string which is just a return.

Comment: @jdweng yes, and I just receive one time with empty string, while it should recevie dozens of lines.

Comment: use While(true) so you wait forever and see if you get more than one response.

Comment: @jdweng the claim is that this process doesn't write to any standard stream though...

Comment: @Caius Jard : there are two issues 1) Without the while the c# is reading data before the app has sent data.  The is no block 2)  When adding a While you need to read until an END character to read all the data.  Read To End will stop when the end of the stream is reached which may occur before the app has finished processing.

Comment: I meant, the claim is that CMD cannot capture the contents of these streams, let alone C#. User has done from `some.exe 0>dbg0.txt` to `some.exe 9>dbg9.txt` incrementally and none of the text files contained any data at all, yet when he runs `some.exe` the console is filled with output

Comment: If anything, Linux programs should be *more* standard when it comes to stdout / stderr handling than Windows-native programs. The problem is almost certainly in the Windows port.

Comment: @tripleee I think what you said makes sense, the program should be working well in Linux. besides, thanks for correct my mistake, my English is really poor.

Comment: Maybe still replace the fugly screen shot with a text transcription; [images of code and error messages are problematic for a number of reasons.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged)

Comment: I also encountered a similar problem when I tried to execute InterfaceCOLMAP.exe. I can get the output from console, but get no standardoutput, either by sync or Async. I also wonder if it is because the InterfaceCOLMAP used non-standard output because it uses SEACAVE::Log::GetInstance() instead of std:cout as output. but when I changed output to std:cout it still does not work